# Como usar Regex para seleccionar parrafos que comiencen solo con letras o numeros

Tags: regex

Quiero utilizar una expresión Regex para seleccionar solamente los párrafos dentro de un código HTML que comiencen con letras o números.

```html
 
 En estos negocios es importante desarrollar competencias diferenciadoras y superiores que se basen en la orientación a resultados, carácter, habilidades interpersonales, capacidades personales y liderar el cambio.
 
<h3>Metodología</h3>

 Se debe trabajar en las actitudes propias de cada persona que permitan realizar actividades necesarias para estas organizaciones y que requieren un desempeño superior y especializado como los análisis de tendencias, de mercados, de canales de comercialización, de acciones de marketing y de posibilidades de alianzas estratégicas.
```

Usando esta expresión `([a-zA-Z0-9].+)` selecciono los párrafos, pero tambien me incluye el que comienza con `<h3>` y quisiera excluir esta linea.

Comment: Pues, así como está, la expresión no indica que el párrafo deba tener ***sólo*** lo que indica el grupo (alfanumérico). Para resolverlo, ponle los símbolos para que haga el match con TODO el párrafo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Usa el delimitador de inicio de la cadena **^**. 
Intentalo con esta expresion

```
(^[a-zA-Z0-9].+)
```

y nos dices el resultado

Comment: En teoría y  en la práctica, funciona! [Test](https://regex101.com/r/X1eNbS/1)

Comment: Con el delimitador solo me selecciona el primer párrafo, el resto de los párrafos no los selecciona, el objetivo es poder incluir entre las etiquetas <p> </p> los párrafos que no estén enmarcados

Comment: Disculpe me di cuenta que si el parrafo comienza con algun espacio en blanco no lo toma, funciona ala perfección

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo tu pregunta por el sentido que le das a la palabra "párrafo".

Si por párrafo te refieres a lo que esté entre los tags `<p></p>` entonces la expresión

```
(?<=\<p\>)([[:alnum:]].+)(?=\<\\p\>)
```

funciona, en cambio, si te refieres a únicamente texto, entones la expresión

```
(^[[:alnum:]].+)
```

funciona. Si te refieres a los dos, entonces, la combinación

```
((^[[:alnum:]].+)|((?<=\<p\>)([[:alnum:]].+)(?=\<\\p\>)))
```

también jala.

Puedes ver un ejemplo de lo que menciono, aquí
https://regex101.com/r/abOYSB/5

Comment: Funciona perfecto, la idea es colocarle al etiqueta <p></p> a los parrafos que no lo tienen, con la opción propuesta por Eduardo Marin (^[a-zA-Z0-9].+) funciona, solo agregando (^\s[a-zA-Z0-9].+) selecciona los que contienen espacios en blanco al inicio

Comment: Perfecto, quizás, al menos para personas como yo, tendría que poner eso en la descripción de tu pregunta.